# What OAuth library would you recommend for a new project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I'm developing a WebServer/DesktopClient app, and was wondering what OAuth library you'd recommend for this new project.

I'm developing in C#.Net 3.5, building a webservice and a winforms app.

Comment: I'd start by looking at http://oauth.net/code/ and seeing which are most active.

Comment: It looks like the devdefined library has the most recent development.

Answer (score 2):

When I started my last project I looked through all available libraries and selected [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/). I appreciated examples and full free support on mailing list from Andrew Arnott.